# What is the best way to disambiguate a tabletop game and a game of one a these games

Tags: word-choice, nouns

In the context of writing a computer program to play multiple tabletop games, I need a way to disambiguate in the code the tabletop games, and an instance of it (a game of a game, if I may say).

I'm French, and we make a clear distinction between both concepts: "Un jeu" means the set of rules, "Une partie" means one game of it.

Right now I started with "Tabletop game" and "Game". However, it's not concise, and as "game" is used in both, it makes it harder to search for specific code.

So, is there a natural and concise way to make a clear distinction for a native speaker using nouns?

Thanks for your time

Comment: This may be one situation where your language has the advantage. The different senses (polysemes) used in "Which game shall we play this afternoon?" and "Do you want another game?" are disambiguated by context in English. We'd use 'board game' if forced to use a more specific term for games like chess, Monopoly, Carcassonne etc.

Comment: What's the context?  Are these labels for menus that the user interacts with? *Games* for the classes and *Sessions* for the instances might work.

Comment: @Juhasz It's for the computer programming code. Having concise and distinct names in the code is very important to code faster later on (new programmers can get into it more easily, and it's better to reduce the number of search results when you search globally for one concept).
Unfortunately, Session is not a good idea here because it is already used in every website to describe the user's session of navigation... So it only creates another ambiguity ;)

Comment: Since this language isn't user-facing, you have more leeway (the terminology only needs to make sense to developers, it doesn't need to be idiomatic English). I'd go with *Game* and *GameSession*.  If you feel that there's too much semantic overlap between *GameSession* and a *web session*, you could try *GamePlay*, *GameBout*, *GameContest*, *GameSitting*, *GamePlaythrough*. If you want to use *Game* to represent the sessions, you could call the board game *GameRulesSet* or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going for "Board Game" and "Game" for now then, because playing is the core feature so I will get the most benefits of using a single word for it.